# WinHttpClient getResponsecontent gzip Encode?

Tags: c++, web, request, gzip, compression

im using the WinHttpClient to get the data from a website using c++.
I have already download the data from the website i want but im having some problems with the websites that are compressed with gzip , is there anyway to obtain the winHttpClient.GetResponseContent() uncompressed?

```
 WinHttpClient getClient(URL);
 getClient.SetAdditionalRequestHeaders(L"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n");
getClient.SetUserAgent(L"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0");
getClient.SendHttpRequest();
```

And the pciture of the message im receiving with the header
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA9Zt.jpg

i have tried also with

```
getClient.SetRequireValidSslCertificates(true);
```

and

```
getClient.SetRequireValidSslCertificates(false);
```

Comment: Are you specifically adding a header-line line `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n`?  If so, you're telling the server that you support compression, but you don't, so remove that header.

Comment: Yes im adding this header, but i have tried to remove and is still not working , maybe its because the URL is coded? im going to edit the main toppic to add some code and pictures